# href string using wild cards

Tags: href, wildcard

Is it possible to use a wild card * in a file name. I have a really long image Tiff file that I want to in the href line but only look for the first 10 to 12 characters or first - in the file.

Comment: In short, no. What if 2 files would match the wildcard

Comment: Well thanks Ward. In my case there can not be a duplicate but that's my case. I guess some php at first will have to do.